# How to lose space in a uitextview

Tags: ios, uitextview

[image: uitextview]

I have the uitextview above and for some reason when a sentence doesn't fit the line, when it goes at the next line leaves a space. Does anyone why this happens?

ps: I haven't added any lines of code that could do that.

Thanks

Comment: which one is the original text? which part does have extra spaces on your view? what you posted is a pink/blurry image with a grey rectangle which does not point anything about your real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check source of the contents of the text view.

It looks like the contained `NSAttributedString` has a paragraph style that uses `firstLineHeadIndent` and `headIndent` to indent the lines of text.

Answer (score 0):

.h file

```
@property(retain) IBOutlet UITextView *terms;
```

.m file

```
self.terms.text = @"some big text";
NSMutableAttributedString* content =  [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
                                       initWithString:self.terms.text];
NSMutableParagraphStyle* para = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
para.headIndent = -10;
para.firstLineHeadIndent = 0;
para.tailIndent = -10;
para.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
para.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
para.paragraphSpacing = 15;
[content addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                value:para range:NSMakeRange(0,1)];
self.terms.attributedText = content;
```